# Why is my Tukey's Test (from Agricolae) null?

Tags: r, statistics, tukey

I am trying to use HSD.test from the Agricolae package to do a Tukey's test on my data. However, my result is always just the word `NULL`.

My data:

```
structure(list(Sample = c(1011L, 1012L, 1014L, 1024L, 1025L, 
    1026L), Collection = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Irrigation = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Rate1", "Rate2", "Rate3", "Rate4", 
    "Rate5"), class = "factor"), Variety = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Hodag", "Lamoka", "Snowden"), class = "factor"), 
    Suc = c(0.7333, 0.4717, 0.5883, 0.6783, 0.8283, 0.6833), 
    Gluc = c(0.03, 0.04, 0.043, 0.075, 0.057, 0.087), L = c(59.48, 
    57.59, 59.25, 66.45, 68.29, 65.65), a = c(4.36, 6.85, 3.43, 
    1.7, 0.78, 2.84), b = c(26.82, 27.6, 26.2, 26.14, 25.37, 
    27.19), NoDefect = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 92L, 100L, 100L), 
    Defect = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Combining the Collection and Irrigation factors (I want to do Tukey's on a group of these 10 total treatments of 2 collection types and 5 irrigation types):

```
Tukey_data <- data %>%
      mutate(Tukey_ID = paste(Collection, Irrigation, sep="_"))
```

Anova:

```
Tukey_data$Tukey_ID <- as.factor(Tukey_data$Tukey_ID) 
TukeyAov <- aov(Suc ~ Tukey_data$Tukey_ID, data = Tukey_data)
```

Tukey's:

```
HSD.test(TukeyAov, "Tukey_ID", group=FALSE)
```

Response:     `NULL`

Any idea why my response is null? Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm guessing you need `HSD.test(TukeyAov, "Tukey_data$Tukey_ID", group=FALSE)`

Comment: Thank you, this seems like it worked! Now, when I use the `print` function, I can see my comparisons and what is different. Do you know how I can take that test use it to see the different letter categories? Such as A, AB, C, etc.?

Comment: Never mind, I found the `print(HSD$groups)` function and that did the trick after changing `group=FALSE` to `group=TRUE`. Thanks again for getting me on the right track!

Comment: To get it work as you expected, you should use `aov(Suc ~ Tukey_ID, data = Tukey_data)`. You do not need to use `$` when you use the `data` argument

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and found that the treatment variable needs to be labelled exactly as it is in the model. It reads it as a string, not a label. In your case, you would need `trt = "Tukey_data$Tukey_ID"`. In another example, when I defined my model, I used `as.factor(Tukey_ID)` and needed to to define treatments as `trt = "as.factor(Tukey_ID)"`

Comment: This was my issue. I hadn't realized that you need to include the dataframe and the column exactly how it appears when you run the aov() function prior to the HSD.test()